# Does Thanos' plan apply to higher order beings?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

We know that Thanos' plan was to

> instantly destroy half of all life in the universe

His plan doesn't appear to apply to lower or non sentient life forms

> if it did half the trees in the final Wakanda scene would have disintegrated too

Does his plan apply to all beings more powerful than himself?

Comment: If they’re *more* powerful than him, could it affect them?

Comment: By the end of the movie, *are* there any beings more powerful than Thanos?  (That we know exist in the MCU, that is?)

Comment: @Adamant It could in the comics, for what it's worth.

Comment: @HarryJohnston We saw The Watchers in Guardians of the Galaxy 2. Not sure if those count as “more powerful”.

Comment: `if it did half the trees in the final Wakanda scene would have disintegrated too` ~> Probability doesn't work like that. Each trees in Wakanda had 50% chance of survival. They all got lucky similar to how all original Avengers survived.

Comment: @Endgame, the odds against that are astronomical.

Answer (score 28):

According to Marvel producer Kevin Feige Thanos' 'finger snap' resulted in the destruction of **half of all life in the universe, not just higher beings.**

> **Q. Are half the animals dead? Are half of the horses gone? Half of the ants?**
>
> **Feige:** *Yes! Yes. All life.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Kevin Feige Still Won’t Tell Us All Marvel’s Future Plans](https://birthmoviesdeath.com/2018/07/08/kevin-feige-still-wont-tell-us-all-marvels-future-plans)</sup></sub>

and

> Cap interjected, his rage uncharacteristically getting the better of
> him, “**That maniac took out half of all life**. Not just on Earth. In the
> universe.”
>
> Nat explained, “Thanos apparently decided that **the universe can’t
> support so much life, so he was going to cull the whole thing down to
> size.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Look Out for the Little Guy by Scott Lang](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Look_Out_for_the_Little_Guy!)</sup></sub>

Comment: All Life... Well with of 1/2 everything your problem doesn't go away, you just reduced the total number.... I mean unless you don't eat things that are alive?

Comment: @Skooba - Yup. That's what I thought too.

Comment: @Skooba, depends whether the problem is food supply or living space.  In most cases the food supply could presumably be brought back up to pre-finger-snap levels fairly quickly anyway.

Comment: gut flora too? 10 minutes after the snap everyone still existing is gonna need to take a massive potty break.

Comment: Weird... I suppose you can breed the flora and fauna to fill the new empty space, but yeah... seems counter productive...

Comment: @KevinMilner - Well, if you're gonna break it down that far, why not keep going?  Technically all the mitochondria in your cells are captured bacteria - if you killed half of every living being's mitochondria, it would probably be fatal to the organism as a whole.  Thus, the only things that would still be alive in the universe would be half of the single-celled organisms.

Comment: Half of all the midichlorians too?!?

Comment: @Celestialgranturismo - No, because Star Wars happened a long time ago

Comment: @Valorum - only from the point of view of the narrator.  We don't know when (or where) they live.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock - We do know that it's not our galaxy and that it's far away

Answer (score 16):

Thanos' plan was

> destroy half of the life forms in the universe because of over-population and lack of resources.

In that, there is a distinction.

> If he deleted all the trees, he would be removing resources leaving the living in the same problem.

So...

> he erased creatures that use up resources without giving back. So trees and non-sentient life are safe, and lower-life forms are okay because they serve a purpose to the biosphere. But humans, as well as other "dominant species", are what are causing there to be limited resources and must be forcibly reduced.

But when you get to things of a "higher order", you're generally talking about unique entities; such as the personification of "the Universe" and "The Beyonder". Since they are unique, you really can't wipe out "half"--which is...

> ...probably why Rocket lived as he is a unique creature onto himself.

The only race I could think of "higher" than Thanos would be the Watchers, in which case, it is likely they too were culled.

I guess a lot of it depends on what you call "higher order"...

Comment: I'm somehow on Thanos's side.

Comment: @SovereignSun I think that was the point-- like Killmonger and lots of others, Thanos is a "good intention [make limited resources go farther] taken to an evil extreme [just slaughter lots of people]" type of villain.

Comment: Except, now that poor cannibal culture is robbed of half its resources. Did you think about *that* Thanos? No, you only ever think about your self!

Comment: @Skooba, When you get to things of a "higher order", you're generally talking about unique entities; such as the personification of "the Universe" and "The Beyonder". Since they are unique, you really can't wipe out "half". It's probably why Rocket lived as he is a unique creature onto himself. The only race I could think of "higher" than Thanos would be the Watchers, in which case, it is likely they too were culled.

Comment: @MivaScott Sounds like you should add that to your answer, with any references if you have them ;-)

Comment: `.. probably why Rocket lived as he is a unique creature onto himself.` ~> That's wrong. Groot was last survivor of his race (said by Collector) and yet he died.

Comment: @TheWasp the Collector never says that. The line is "I never thought I'd meet a Groot." There's no implication that there's only one Groot.

Comment: @OrangeDog He requested stem of his body after he dies because he was the last one and Collector is fond of collecting unique objects.

Comment: There are some very bold statements here, but not a lick of proof

Answer (score 11):

The [new trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hA6hldpSTF8) for *Avengers: Endgame* gives us an in-universe confirmation and a bit of a distinction from [Kevin Feige's quote](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/190910/57310)...

> [Natasha Romanov] Thanos did exactly what he said he was gonna do, he wiped out **fifty percent of all living creatures.**

The distinction of *[creatures](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/creature)* is an important one as it it defined as animals. So this is why all the trees and such are still standing. It also leaves room for unicellular organisms to remain.

Comment: I am not a biologist, but from my quick search, unicellular organisms do not seem be classified as animals, and therefore *could* be excluded from a definition of "creature".

Comment: In other words Thanos just screwed over the remaining creatures.  Kill off 50% of all creatures that are involved in propagation of plant species - especially plants that are eaten by other creatures - and you have a recipe for environmental collapse.

Comment: -1 You are placing *far* too much weight on Black Widow's choice of words "creatures," as opposed to, say, Thanos' choice of words "life" (e.g., in conversation with Gamora in *Infinity War*).

Comment: @Lexible Maybe you are placing FAR too much weight on Thanos' choice of word "life"...in-universe Natasha saw the aftermath and is able to asses what is still there and what isn't.

Answer (score -2):

Based on the precedent of the comics, he doesn't have the power to delete the truly cosmic-level entities - not that any of them have been )or will be) seen in the films.

Part of the problem is that while there are any number of beings of cosmic or universal power in the Marvel Universe, only a couple of the relatively weaker ones have been explicitly introduced in the films.

Dormammu is incredibly powerful, but he's nothing compared to, say, beings like the In-Betweener or the Living Tribunal. It'd be an argument whether or not the Celestials are more powerful than a Gauntlet-powered Thanos, but it'd be close. The Watchers are very powerful in the comics, but save for a cameo, we've no hard data about them in the MCU.

The truly cosmic entities joined the various fights against Thanos in the comics, but I don't recall any of them being destroyed or Snapped by him (corrections accepted).  If we use that as a standard, it suggests that he doesn't have the power to delete them in the filmic universe either.

I suspect they won't be used in the movie, so the question will remain unanswered It'd take too long to explain who they are, not to mention we want to see the heroes win, not a literal *deus ex machina* where some totally new bunch of beings swoop in and save the day.

Comment: There's no good indication either way but there's no reason to assume that Thanos' 'snap' didn't work on *every* form of life in the universe.

Comment: I based my assumption on the comics, which seemed a good start.  The hypothesis is that Thanos can only affect being whom he is more powerful than. So ants, trees, accountants, would all be subject to his power, while the "upper level" cosmic entities would not. He is certainly on par with some of them and their power, and can stand toe to toe with them in battle, and defeat, possibly even kill one, but not so powerful that he could wish one into the cornfield.

Comment: "It'd be an argument whether or not the Celestials are more powerful than a Gauntlet-powered Thanos, but it'd be close." If we are referring to comics, I believe a few celestials joined in on trying to fight Thanos (w/ all 6 stones) and were soundly defeated - along with beings like Galactus and Eternity. It wasn't close.

Answer (score -2):

The-One-Above-All (hyphens) is the Primal Entity of the Marvel Multiverse. As often as people want to pit Thanos and the Infinity Gauntlet against other beings, only nigh-supreme cosmic beings generally have any chance against their combined power.

[image: The Living Tribunal]

But the-One -Above-All trumps all other powers in the Marvel Multiverse. It has supremacy over all things and has no equal save itself.

The Infinity Gauntlet is nothing in the face of its overwhelming capacity. This is one of its depictions as Above-All-Others from Thanos: The Infinity Finale #3.
The One-Above-All is apparently responsible for the existence of all life in the Multiverse and possibly beyond, and is the master and sole superior of the cosmic overseer and arbitrator known as the Living Tribunal, whose faces, embodying equity, vengeance and necessity respectively, are in perfect alignment with one another as it passes judgment.
While Thanos has few equals or betters while he wears it, the Infinity Gauntlet is one level of Infinity lower than needed to be a threat to The-One-Above-All. Even Thanos knows this and has done his very best to not bring himself to the focused attention of this Entity above all others.

Comment: Can you present any evidence that The-One-Above-All exists in the MCU?  [This related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/153485/5930) about whether the MCU is in fact part of the Marvel comics multiverse never got a definitive answer.

Comment: You talk about The-one-above-all and put a picture of The living tribunal. What are you tryin' to say? I'm lost....

Answer (score -3):

Looking through the other answers here no one seems to address the OP’s concern about the Wakanda scene specifically - expecting to see 1/2 of every living thing (including grass and trees) vanish before our eyes. Eliminating half of anything doesn’t force you to be fair. In a room full of 100 trees with 1 bird in each tree, you can eliminate half the life by killing all the trees, all the birds, 75 trees and 25 birds, or half of the birds and trees. In the end, you start with 200 living things and end with 100 either way. In fact if the universe had a sense of humor Thanos’ snap could have left every humanoid alive and just wiped out some grasses, mosquitoes, viruses and some algae. As long as it equaled 1/2 of all life. Then he would really be the Mad Titan!

The only reason trees and grass in Wakanda would vanish would be if he eliminated “one half of each *life form* in the universe.” (How do you even eliminate half of the "Ego the Living Planets?") That is not what he said. After the snap, the number of living things in the universe was half of what it was before, and that is the only rule.

As far as higher order beings, there is no controversy over why even unique life forms like Galactus, One-Above-All, The Collector, or Eternity did not need to be killed. It applied to every living thing as a group. They just didn't lose the lottery.

Comment: The top two answers address trees and grass, albeit the first one indirectly.

Comment: No those answers leave out any explanation to why 1/2 the trees didn’t vanish in the movie. They broadly try to talk about what is and is not a living thing.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the first part of [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/186954/58193) specifically addresses trees: _"If he deleted all the trees, he would be removing resources leaving the living in the same problem."_

Comment: Ok, The OP said “if it did half the trees **in the final Wakanda scene** would have disintegrated too.” Literally that answer never even mentions the Wakanda scene. Or the movie at all for that matter.  Just because an answer makes an obscure rationalized reference to the topic of a question doesn’t mean the question was answered. I simply explained why the scene in question did not show 1/2 of the trees vanishing, because no one else addressed it.

Comment: @VogonPoet it was just for the sake of reference, as an example. You can't be serious that he was talking _only_ about the trees in Wakanda? In that case we can have millions of questions asking only about trees in every city/country across the galaxy.

Comment: Fair enough I think that's a bit of an unnecessary and pedantic distinction but okay. I also argue [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/218582/58193) that the 50% was on a per planet/species level so I disagree with parts of your answer here.

Comment: Well I can be serious that assuming what an OP implies when the text is right in front of you will always end badly. He imagined there was some contradiction, he conceived a question, it deserved an answer. I’m sure in some way he thought “every species shall be divided equally in two at that instant.” No one else cared to give a canonical solution to the alleged problem.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot that’s a fair deduction but as you yourself wrote there is no canonical answer. Assuming the stones make assumptions is a perilous journey. Canon makes no requirement to have 1/2 of anything at all vanish on screen. Even your own argument - half a planet - could be accomplished by killing insects. You *want* the process to be fair with no justification.

Comment: I mean I justified my reasoning in the answer but okay. It only makes sense for Thanos' motives to do it that way. I'll leave the discussion here though.

Comment: Fwiw, I address trees and such in my answer...

Comment: I just clarified I was talking about the OP confusion

Comment: The second answer directly answers regarding trees (and the question is asking about trees, not specifically the trees in Wakanda; I think it is clear that Wakanda is being used as an example). There seems to be one good point in this answer (half all life, not necessarily half of each individual sub type), but you also ignore why it ignores all higher beings (i think your trying to imply 'Because luck' seems a bit of a reach especially with far better explanations). This answer might have some worth, but it should be rewritten for clarity.