# Did the event in Infinity War affect animals?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

We know that Thanos

> killed half of the universe, but did he only kill advances lifeforms or simpler ones, too?

Is there any evidence or examples where Thanos cut the line between different lifeforms?

I think Thanos is a really consequent character, so it would be reasonable

> to disintegrate half of all life.

There was a question (unfortunately I can't find it anymore), if the event affected half of the population of every planet, or the whole universe. So my follow-up question would be:

Did the event affect half of all lifeforms on a planet as a whole or only half of one specific species separately?

> Note that on the latter case the chance that all humans die/live can vary much more, because only one litre of water contains millions (or billions) of animals, so the number of humans is insignificant.

Comment: Feels like dupe.

Comment: Probably - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186884/does-thanos-plan-apply-to-higher-order-beings

Comment: Definitely a dupe.

Comment: I don't see how this a dupe. The other question is asking about "higher order" beings and while it does talk about trees and things, it does not specifically address animals. While a complete answer may answer both questions, I see no such answer at this time. VTRO.