# In the comics did Thanos "kill" just sentient beings or all creatures with the snap?

Tags: marvel, comics, thanos, the-infinity-gauntlet

In the trailer for *Avengers: Endgame* Black Widow states that:

> Thanos did what he planned to do, killed half of all living creatures in the universe.

Now that line suggests that this was not just limited to sentient beings (Humans, Asgardians, Krull etc.) but that half of everything, from the tiniest insects, to birds, sheep, cows etc. all vanished.

**In the comics**, is this indicated to be the results of the snap, or is it only sentient beings that are killed?

Comment: [Related question about the MCU rather than the comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186884/58193).

Comment: In MCU, its sentient beings. The rhino doesn't die, but Groot does. I think that if the Stones are smart enough to create things like Ultron ( with help from Tony) they can tell if something is sentient or not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It would appear as if Thanos killed all *animal* life with the snap, which would include sentient and non-sentient creatures.

---

The line in the comics is:

> My love bade me to *extinguish* the *light* of half the universe's populace.

Populace would imply every living creature rather than just sentient beings.

This can be seen in the page below from *Infinity Gauntlet* Issue #1:

[image: Infinity Gauntlet_ Issue #1 page showing Thanos considering the snap]

This is indeed confirmed later on when we also see that other species are indeed affected as cattle farmers report that cows have vanished also, pets are missing and scientists have concluded it is all *animal* life.

> New bulletins coming in indicate that *humans* are *not* the only creatures falling victim to the *Great Disappearance*.
>
> *Cattle farmers* report that half their *herds* have vanished.
>
> Indeed, scientists believe half of all *animal life* on the planet disappeared along with the missing *human victims*.

[image: Infinity Gauntlet_ Issue #1 page showing animal life disappearing]

Plant life would not seem to be affected, the reports all talk about population and beings and the news report specifically mentions only animal life. There are also various images of clusters of trees which whilst possible would be more unlikely given the randomness of the event. See the below image from *Infinity Gauntlet* Issue #2.

[image: Infinity Gauntlet Issue #2 panel showing a cluster of trees]

Comment: Did plant life also disappear? Like, during the Infinity War Snap scene, I'm failry sure I didn't see half of the trees in that forest turn to dust.

Comment: What about `Fungi` and all those `Prokaryota`s?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot That then makes me wonder if there is are any sentient plant species in the Marvel universe, and did they disappear as well? I'm guessing there's no evidence of that either way.

Comment: @DavidK If Groot counts under that definition of yours then yes sentient plant species are affected.

Comment: Of course! How could I forget Groot??

Comment: Killing half the plants would kind of defeat the entire purpose, wouldn't it?  The idea being there isn't enough food for everyone, so if you kill half the people AND half the food, you've not changed that situation at all. (Never mind the effect this whole thing would have on carnivores, etc. Really ecology is way more complicated than Thanos seems to make it out to be.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Plus the whole "some species may suffer imminent extinction if their numbers are reduced by that much, leading to ecosystem collapse, vastly exacerbating the problems allegedly solved", "a lot of babies were left without parents that need them and so died in addition to the snap", etc.  Ultimately this is a case of comic book writers not doing their homework, and movie writers not fixing it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman No, the question asks about the comics not the MCU. In the comics Thanos does this to please Mistress Death not to save on resources as he does in the films.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Or, alternately, it's a case of a genocidal madman all hopped up on divine power going for the big stick answer rather than considering the deeper implications of his actions.

Comment: What about supreme beings, e.g. Celestials? They are no doubt sentient beings. Were they also affected and killed?

Comment: @Nzall Edited to include about plant life but I believe the answer is no, it did not disappear.

Comment: I would think "populace" implies sentient beings, not all beings, even though that is contradicted by the rest of your answer.

Comment: "Populace would imply every living creature rather than just sentient beings." Like Azor, I don't think that's implied by the meaning of the word *populace*, even though it turns out to be the case.

Comment: The term is _sapient_, people. _Any_ creature able to perceive outside information through its senses is sentient.