# How did they feed people at the end of "Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

With half of all people gone, the infrastructure and food must have been greatly reduced. In five years, how would they have fed a population that suddenly doubled?

Comment: It's called rationing.

Comment: They eat a lot of meat (that also came back)?  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/206660/101407

Comment: Delicious, juicy whale meat, straight from the Hudson!

Comment: Well, when the snap happened, we still had food supply which fed 100% of the population minus the livestock. Assuming people are still making food, there should be enough food to feed the people who came back until everything was in working order again. Now, what happened to the people who disappeared while in an airplane?

Comment: @Huangism But why would people have been making twice as much food as was needed? You can’t suddenly increase food production just because you now have more workers — crops and animals take months to reach maturity.

Comment: @DavidW The animals may have come back, but their fodder hasn’t. Depending on the time of year that may not matter for grass-fed livestock, but a lot of cattle in the US are going to starve before they can be slaughtered and frozen.

Answer (score 9):

At the end of Endgame, the <s>un-snappening</s> Blip resulted in the return of all of the humans ***and other forms of life*** that Thanos destroyed in the Snap.

[image]
<sub><sup>*Scott Lang (Ant Man) looks at a bird nesting in a tree which is now miraculously two birds.*</sup></sub>

This is confirmed in Scott Lang's in-universe autobiography [*Look out for the Little Guy!*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Look_Out_for_the_Little_Guy!).

> What was weird was, suddenly there were way more birds than before.
> You might even say probably twice as many. But somehow, strangely,
> that instantaneous explosion of life filled me with a tiny feeling of
> optimism I couldn’t even remember experiencing, because it had been so
> long.

---

Given that the 'Blip' resulted in the return of a significant number of animals that are now available for harvesting, I think we can presume that the governments of the world would have had contingency plans in place in case the population returned as fast as they disappeared. This would include stockpiling of rationable items like MREs, rapidly harvesting animals for meat, gathering crops for storage, etc.

Comment: I was under the impression that the snap didn’t affect plant life.

Comment: ["All life!"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/190910/20774)

Comment: Aye I’ve seen that answer but the evidence I’ve seen in the films contradict it and I _think_ I’ve seen an interview where it says sentient or words to that affect which would exclude plant life. Would have to try and dig it up though.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot:   [Umm...](https://img.cinemablend.com/filter:scale/quill/4/9/5/1/4/c/49514cf51fd858d57ced3996908cd4f5b000da4c.jpg?mw=600)

Comment: @ThePopMachine Groot isn’t exactly your every day plant life though is he.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: joke.

Comment: Was cellular life that makes up food included?

Comment: Also, I would think any life that qualifies as a resource would not snap away since the whole point was to make it so being had enough resources

Comment: @User47014 - Thanos is concerned with mineral resources. He's calculated how long the universe will last before it's incapable of sustaining life and wants to extend that

Comment: @Valorum Except, human population doubles about every 65 years.  That rate will (obviously) vary from species to species, but rather than "saving the universe", he only buys it a century or two - which on the cosmic scale is over like [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXavNm6y8OE&t=69).

Comment: @Chronocidal - Thanos' thinking is that people will see the benefit of a reduced population and will control themselves without his constant involvement

Comment: With the population of meat animals doubling instantly, there would have been a problem of *too much* food. Think about it; suddenly feedlots and ranches and farms have twice the animals they had a moment before, way beyond their capacity. Slaughterhouses and meat processing plants would have had to go into overdrive in order to deal with the situation. After that, it's a matter of distribution and storage, and most governments would have put serious effort into that in order to give them time for more long-term solutions.

Comment: @KeithMorrison - It's worth pointing out that hunger isn't caused by a lack of food, it's caused by a lack of good governance. The world produces enough calories to feed a population of 30Bn or more *already*, as long as we're willing to only eat sufficient calories to maintain ourselves.

Comment: The directors of Far from Home actually talked about the gaps in logic about the snap, as they said 50% of all living things, does that include the bacteria in peoples gut, bacteria that we need to live? Or Virus's. They discussed it with th erusso's and kevin feige and decided the best thing to do was not to worry or think about it to much.

Answer (score 7):

*Far From Home* shows that a number of issues have been caused by the Blip, Aunt May is hosting a benefit to raise money for all those made homeless by the blip (she says she reappeared in her old apartment to find other people living there.) I imagine other charities have been set up and governments have had to scramble to deal with the sudden influx of people. There are also the added issues, people who claimed to have been snapped when they where not, pay out of life insurance now needing to be paid back, children and babies blipping back with no idea where their parents are living now. Parents blipping back and having to hunt down and find their children who have had 5 years dealing with the loss of their families. I imagine as well that a number of people committed suicide, died of natural causes etc. They won't have returned and people who were snapped out will have to deal with the emotional fallout of finding out they have returned, but their mother/father/husband/wife/son/daughter is dead. I imagine the impact will reverberate around the MCU for a few more films yet.

Comment: That sounds about right. A few more films for people to forget the most significant event in human history.

Comment: How does that answer the OP's question ? You just had more questions >.<

Comment: I am showing that Far from Home shows how one aspect of the Blip is handled, so far this is the thing that has been shown by the MCU.