# Were other dimensions affected by Thanos' Snap?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Doctor Strange*, we are made aware of the different universes and especially the one one in which Dormammu resides, which is the Dark Dimension.

Were beings in other dimensions also affected by the Snap Thanos did in *Avengers: Infinity War*? Were beings like Dormammu also affected by the Snap or were they more than just a creature and the Snap did not have any effect on him?

My knowledge says Thanos himself says the following in *Avengers: Endgame*:

> The universe required correction. After that, the stones served no purpose beyond temptation.

Which confuses me, are other dimensions also affected?

Comment: The question of whether it would affect beings like Dormmamu is [answered here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186884/58193). Asking whether it would affect his dimension though seems reasonable. I've also edited this to mention dimensions and not universes as the two terms do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, thanks and This is the intresting part!. Would it affect others?

Comment: I think that for know, we don't have a definitive answer. But I'm holding out hopes we will.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Yes

### Exhibit A:

The Quantum Realm is considered a separate dimension, as part of the Multiverse in the MCU.

- https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Multiverse
- https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Quantum_Realm

The quantum realm is first introduced in the MCU in the *Ant-Man* movie. It is explained by Dr. Pym that the quantum realm is a distinct reality, although he does not state explicitly that it is a different dimension. [From the transcript](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Ant-Man) (emphasis mine):

> - Dr. Hank Pym: It means that you would enter a quantum realm.
> - Scott Lang: What does that mean?
> - Dr. Hank Pym: It means that you would ***enter a reality*** where all concepts of time and space become irrelevant as you shrink for all eternity. Everything that you know, and love, gone forever.

In the *Doctor Strange* movie the Quantum realm is shown again when the Ancient One first tells Strange of other dimensions. [This is confirmed in the Director's commentary](https://screenrant.com/doctor-strange-ant-man-quantum-realm/):

> This image here is obviously a nod to Ant-Man and the Quantum Realm, acknowledging that as one of the mysterious realms of existence.
>
> -Scott Derrickson, director for Doctor Strange

Here's a video showing Both the *Ant-Man* and *Doctor Strange* movie scenes having to do with the Quantum realm. Strange enters the Quantum Realm at the 0:47 mark and exits at 0:55.

### Exhibit B:

In the SDCC 2019 panel, *Infinity War* and *Endgame* writers Christopher Markus and Stephen McFeely [confirmed the snap is interdimensional](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/avengers-endgame-writers-sdcc-2019-panel/).

> Did the Quantum realm get snapped? The writers say the stones do no differentiate, so Scott surviving was the lucky flip. Ant-Man was really lucky, it seems.

Answer (score 5):

It would be highly unlikely that Thanos' Snap affected other dimensions. Firstly, we have no indication he even knew there were other dimensions; the closest we see to him seeing this is when he fights Strange. However, most of what Strange does there is just ordinary "magic".

Thanos is also correcting the universe to help save it and the life within it. If he were to affect some of the other dimensions which don't have direct life, for example, the Mirror Dimension, that might cause more problems than it solves.

> **Thanos:** Little one, it's a simple calculus. This universe is finite, its resources finite. If life is left unchecked, life will cease to exist. It needs correction.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Some of the dimensions are also more parallel worlds than life giving places, for example, the Astral and Mirror Dimensions. It wouldn't make sense to affect those in the first place as they don't harbour life.

And lastly, of the other dimensions we see only the Dark Dimension has any life within it (that I'm aware of) and that life is only Dormammu. It wouldn't make sense to kill him for the reasons of the Snap in the first place. And as he and the Dark Dimension exist outside of time it might not even be possible. Strange was only able to affect Dormammu in *Doctor Strange* because he took the Time Stone into the Dark Dimension. It's possible that the Time Stone can't affect it when outside of it and as such the might of the other 5 Infinity Stones is not enough for a full Snap.

---

I just want to tack a note on the end though that with *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* coming out in a few years we might get a more explicit answer then. Even though it is likely to be set after *Avengers: Endgame*.

Comment: It may be set before endgame, are you sure that it's set after endgame?

Comment: @StellaRigeo I only said it's likely to be set after. I don't know if it is or not; I've not looked that much into it yet as things change over the years.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The stones from one universe would be useless in the other (in the comics). This was shown when Darkseid tried to get them all. So I guess the overall answer is 'No effect on other dimensions/universes'.

Comment: @Shreedhar I think dimensions are meant to be different than universes. But of course as you say that’s comics logic, no proof it holds true in the MCU.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yeah you're right. I just put it as a note. Anyways, the Mirror dimension is the key! check my answer

Comment: Yeah, in Marvel you have multiple universes, and each universes encompasses its own dimensions and has its own version of the infinity stones. For example, each universe would have its own hell.

Answer (score 5):

### Short answer, No!

---

### Doctor Strange's action in Avengers: Infinity War

During the short one-to-one fight that ensued on Titan between Doctor Strange and Thanos, Strange did try to trap Thanos in the mirror dimension. And as the Ancient One puts it:

> **The Ancient One**: You’re advancing quickly with your sorcery skills. You need a safe space to practice your spells. You are now inside the Mirror Dimension. Ever present but undetected. ***The real world isn’t affected by what happens here. We use the Mirror Dimension to train, surveil, and sometimes to contain threats***. You don’t want to be stuck in here without your sling ring. 
>  <sub>*Doctor Strange*</sub>

This supports the point that trapping Thanos (iff Strange was successful) would've prevented him from Snapping life from our dimension.

**NOTE**: Scott Lang's survival could've been the key that the Snap doesn't affect other dimensions. But since this theory is officially [rejected](https://www.cbr.com/avengers-endgame-markus-torpedo-snap-theory/) by the writers, this one instance in the movies [*kind of*] supported the claim.

Comment: +1 but this only confirms it wouldn't affect the Mirror Dimension of course. The others have different factors to them like Dark Dimension being outside of time.

Comment: Dormammu's realm was a form of alternative dimension and the Time Stone worked just fine in there...

Comment: I highly doubt that something as simple as putting Thanos in the mirror dimension would have any impact whatsoever. He'd have just broken out.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, Valorum: you do have a point there. the answer would then be - "depends on the writers" :p

Comment: @Valorum he did actually break it as well. I thought it wouldn't have been possible to break it from the inside (just basing it on the Ancient One's words though).

Comment: @Shreedhar - Possession of three Infinity Stones basically makes him the most powerful being inside the universe.

Comment: Thanos contained a piece of the mirror dimension and threw it back at Strange. He could very well use either the reality or space stones to go in and out of such realms.

Comment: "this only confirms it wouldn't affect the Mirror Dimension of course" — I don't think it confirms that at all. The point of the Infinity Stones in the gauntlet is that you're basically omnipotent. Maybe the Mirror Dimension would contain them, but if so, one would assume that Doctor Strange would have snuck up behind Thanos and put him there.

Comment: “Scott Lang's survival could've been the key that the Snap doesn't affect other dimensions” — do we know that the quantum realm is another dimension? Isn't it our dimension, just really small parts of it?

Comment: When Thanos was on Titan he didn't yet have all the infinity stones, so the fact that Doctor Strange tried to trap him in the mirror dimension doesn't necessarily mean that even someone in possession of all the stones would be unable to affect the real world from the mirror dimension. Also, even if you take the line "The real world isn’t affected by what happens here" to be all-encompassing (as opposed to just a sort of 'for all practical purposes' statement), it doesn't necessarily imply that the mirror dimension is unaffected by the real world, let alone all alternate dimensions.

Comment: @Valorum Strange created the loop **outside** the dark dimension, so the time stone wasn't really affecting it but everything around it in the real world.