# Would all the not yet emerged Celestials like Tiamut not have been starved 50% during the "Blip"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021

Would the not yet emerged Celestials have reduced energy source during the Blip - and if so, would that not have been a good reason to have the Eternals interfere with Thanos' plans?

Comment: Your second question is a second question in itself and should be asked as such else this would end up being too broad. However, that said it is presumably answered by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186884/58193).

Comment: The answer is in the second half

Comment: Why ask a question halfway through a film?

Comment: "would that not have been a good reason to have the Eternals interfere with Thanos' plans" — there's no indication that the Eternals or Celestials would have known what Thanos' plans were.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite True - if so, then poor planning by the leader of the Eternals after realising that the Avengers actions positively influenced number of ppl on the planet - so they should have tracked or used their friendship with for example Thor

Comment: https://collider.com/eternals-why-didnt-they-stop-thanos/

Comment: @mplungjan: "the Avengers actions positively influenced number of ppl on the planet" — uh, you did see *Age of Ultron*,  right? Also the Eternals are primarily on earth to fight Deviants. For the most part, they're meant to leave humans to figure out how to thrive on their own, which includes learning to defend themselves from non-Deviant cataclysmic threats.

Comment: Well, the non-deviant cataclysmic threats were defended by a few one could discuss their humanity...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

##### “Would the not yet emerged Celestials have reduced energy source during the Blip?”

Yes. Ajak says that the disappearance of half of earth’s population for 5 years delayed Tiamut’s emergence.

##### What are the Eternals for then?

The Eternals are primarily deployed to prevent the Deviants from wiping out intelligent life on earth before it has a chance to get going.

Aside from that, they're meant to mostly leave humanity to learn how to deal with stuff on its own, which includes defending against cataclysmic threats like Thanos — and apparently includes *creating* cataclysmic threats like Ultron, who seems like a greater risk to continued life on earth (and thus sustenance for Little Baby Tiamut) than Thanos' original 50% off strategy, but didn’t inspire any Eternal intervention (as far as we know).

It’s implied in the scene with Ajak and Phastos that his limited technological assistance contributed to the creation of nuclear weapons, which were equally capable of wiping out most of humanity, but also weren’t something the Eternals felt they should deal with.

Presumably, in the long run, letting the Avengers (and the rest of the world) get on with things by themselves has a better chance of ensuring that humanity eventually reaches the required size. The Celestials have been doing this for quite a long time, they've probably learned a thing or two (and/or decided that proper farming is too boring to do on a cosmic scale).

##### Why didn’t the Eternals fight Thanos?

There’s no indication that the Eternals were aware of Thanos, or his plans. Hulk alerts the Avengers at the start of *Infinity War*, but they only seem to have a day or so (where they’re mainly trying to arrange an emergency Mind Stone-ectomy for poor Vision) before Thanos arrives on earth and gets the job done.

As far as we know, they didn’t hold a press conference to let the people of earth know exactly what Thanos had in mind, so there’s no indication that the Eternals would have been aware of his plan to instantly remove half of Little Baby Tiamut’s food source. (And at that point, it was only Ajak and Ikaris who even knew of Tiamut’s existence.)

Even if they *had* been aware of it, they might not have felt the need to do anything about it. They’ve been on earth for thousands of years, and the Celestials have been doing this for millions of years. While Thanos clearly believes that removing half the universe’s population will suddenly make the other half realise the error of their ways and stop expanding their populations, my money’s on humanity getting their numbers back up to Celestial-birthing level within a century or two in a universe where the second snap doesn’t happen — history tells us that, in general, humans quite like reproducing.

Comment: This is a bad answer IMO - I know it was what was given in the film why the Eternals shouldn't protect Earth from Thanos but it's weak because 1st Thanos affected the entire universe, 2nd wouldn't the 'blip' affect the Celestials?

Comment: @Mr.Boy “Thanos affected the entire universe” — so what? The Eternals on earth definitely weren’t given a mission to defend the entire universe. “wouldn’t the ‘blip’ affect the Celestials?’ — yes. The movie says it did, by delaying Tiamut’s birth. On whether the effect would have been permanent if the Avengers hadn’t brought everyone back, that kind of depends on whether you’re drinking your Kool-Aid from a ‘Thanos was right’ mug.

Comment: Thanos was banking on people taking the hint and not repopulating to their original levels.

Comment: @Valorum: he sure was!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite so what? Well the Eternals prime purpose is to serve the Celestials, that's what. This is higher than their mission on Earth. Thanos threatens their entire species, since surely half of them would be wiped out too.

Comment: @Mr.Boy: "the Eternals prime purpose is to serve the Celestials, that's what" — sure. And did the Celestials tell the Eternals to go fight Thanos? Or did the Celestials, in fact, tell the Eternals not to interfere with human affairs? (Are you sure you watched the movie? Maybe fire it up again and take some notes this time.) "Thanos threatens their entire species, since surely half of them would be wiped out too" — sure, although as I now mention above, there's no indication that the Celestials had heard of Thanos, or his plan.

Comment: if Star Trek taught me anything it's that a prime directive is only as important and non-violable as it needs to be for the plot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SmilyLily for pointing me to the answer elsewhere - I should have looked there before asking

[Tiamut the Communicator](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Tiamut_the_Communicator)

> In 2018, Thanos used the Infinity Stones to wipe out half of all life in the universe. This deeply affected the unborn Tiamut, and delayed the Emergence due to a lack of lifeforms to grow off of. However, when the victims of the Snap were resurrected in 2023 by the Avengers, the population was now enough to trigger Tiamut's Emergence.

Comment: I'm not seeing any actual evidence on that website, merely conjecture

Comment: Are we always able to get absolute evidence for stuff only hinted at in the MCU?

Comment: Sometimes, through scripts and interviews, cast and crew commentaries and Q&A sessions, we can confirm details that weren't in the films. In this instance the person writing this wiki has just pointed at 'The Eternals' as their source, and not bothered to justify their claim.

Comment: Ppl here are really harsh on with the downvotes and I cannot even delete the question

Answer (score -1):

I believe the movie did not make it clear whether celestials emerge one after the other or if there are even others that are in that process at the same time.

The way I understood it was that there are not several celestial seeds planted at the same time. So the snap would only have affected Tiamut.
But yes, it must have affected him. The way the MCU wiki says it, the snap didn't exactly hurt Tiamut, but it did delay his emergence.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are multiple Celestials being grown at the same time across the universe, and the movie hinted that, since there are Eternals in other planets.